# Error installing rstan on R and cygwin on Windows 7

Tags: r, stan

I'm having trouble trying to install rstan at my server running R (version 3.0.1) using Windows 7 (64-bits).
I installed Rcpp and inline, and I got `"* DONE (rstan)"`. However, when I run

`fit <- stan(model_code = schools_code, data = schools_dat,iter = 1000, chains = 4)`

I get the followig error:

```
Erreur dans compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
De plus : Message d'avis :
l'exécution de la commande 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file16bc2e56893.cpp 2> file16bc2e56893.cpp.err.txt' renvoie un statut 1
```

Does any of you know what to do?

Comment: try asking on the [stan users list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/stan-users) ?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that Windows users are advised to use RTools rather than Cygwin  compilers. Search with "RTools windows r" and also read the "R Extensions Manual".

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved. I have to check the 32-bits with 64-bits when installing the JAGS 3.4.0